# Difference between object creation using `new ClassName` and `new ClassName()` in PHP

Tags: php, syntax

I know, in PHP, we can create an object using `new ClassName` and also using `new ClassName()` (notice the parenthesis). Is there ANY difference between both of these ways at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, no difference whatsoever. If you don't need to pass parameters to the constructor, the parentheses are entirely superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no difference.

The `()` is required only if you have to pass parameters to the constructor, otherwise it could be omitted.